# Double Integral over triangular region

Tags: integration, multiple-integral

$\displaystyle\int\int_{R}x\,\mathrm{d}A$ over the triangular region R enclosed by the $x + 2y =2$, $x = 0$, and $y = 0$.

I need help to solve it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Those three lines don't enclose a triangle (or anything)

Comment: Hi @Ninad, thanks. So it is wrong in the questions?

Comment: @Adilah Yes, it is a wrong question. You can easily sketch those 3 lines and convince yourself they don't enclose anything at all.

Comment: @Adilah Could there be a typo in the question.  For example, changing one of the constraints to $x + 2y = 1$ would mean that a triangular region was enclosed.  Also, assuming that a triangle region is enclosed, couldn't the area then be computed via a **single** rather than double integration?  Also, **please show your work,** re what you have tried and where you are having trouble.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment @DonAntonio

Comment: Thanks a lot @user2661923

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\int x\ dA$ will give you the $x$ coordinate of the centroid of A

A has vertexes $(2,0),(0,1),(0,0)$  The centroid is $(\frac 23, \frac 13)$

$\frac 23$

You want to learn how to set up the limits of integration?

I suggest you always start with a sketch of your region.  Draw a vertical (or horizontal) line through the your sketch of the region.

[image]

How would you describe the endpoints of that line as equations in terms of x.

One end is $(x,0)$  the other end is $(x,1 - \frac 12 x)$

This gives us our limits for y.

$\int (\int_0^{1-\frac 12 x} x\ dy) \ dx$

And what are our limits for $x?$  The biggest $x$ can be is $2$ the smallest is $0.$

$\int_0^2 (\int_0^{1-\frac 12 x} x\ dy) \ dx$

If you want to change the order of integration use the horizontal line instead.  Find the equations, in terms of y, that describe the endpoints, and find the total range of $y.$

$\int_0^1 (\int_0^{2-2y} x \ dx)\ dy$

Comment: Thanks a lot, Doug! Its perfect!